# Intuitive online resources/books for statistics?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, self-learning

(Sorry for any spelling/grammatical mistake. I am from South America.)

This semester I took my first Statistics course in college, and I feel that ever since the concept of the $T$ distribution was introduced by my teacher, everything became the opposite of intuitive, and it feels like that Statistics is all about applying the "formula", get the answer, interpret it, and done.

Can anyone suggest any book(s)/online resources that can explain Statistics intuitively? (Like 3b1b explains calculus with visual proofs and animations) I think it is very important for me to understand this topic as much as I can because I am pursuing a data science undergrad program (I think that is what it is called in english) and as far as I am concerned, data science is mainly about Statistics.

Comment: I would argue that the entire reason we do statistics is that reality is often counter-intuitive. I would expect you to find yourself astonished or baffled at certain results. So if you're struggling a little I think that's natural and normal as you first approach the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find [MarinStatsLectures](https://www.youtube.com/@marinstatlectures) YouTube channel really helpful for situations like this. Visit the channel and browse through the playlists that might interest you.

For now, you could watch his [Statistics Course for Beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AN3UkzE3HMg&list=PLqzoL9-eJTNAB5st3mtP_bmXafGSH1Dtz&pp=iAQB) or his [Statistics Course for Data Science](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AN3UkzE3HMg&list=PLqzoL9-eJTNBZDG8jaNuhap1C9q6VHyVa&pp=iAQB).